# How do I expose a service to different frontends?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I want to create a microservice for "orders". The service will have typical actions like "get orders" or "create an order".

I would like to expose this service in two ways:

- User frontend: If you call /orders, you will see **your** orders
- Support frontend: if you call /orders, you will see **all** the orders of all the users

I would like to deploy one API (orders) that can be called from 2 API gateways (user and support). But, I don't know how to do it without duplicating code.

Is this the right approach?

I'm using AWS Apigateway + Lambda + Serverless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some way you're being able to differentiate the user that is making the request inside your lambda function, because you need to get only its orders. Based on that I'm considering that you're receiving some kind of token in your lambda where you can extract the correct user.

Considering that scenario, one standard solution to your problem is add something to your token that differentiate if the user is from the support group or not. Normally you add a claim to the token informing that he/she is part of the support group. Then inside your lambda you check this token and give a different answer based on your requirements. But for that solution, you'll need to have means to add new claims/manage your identity provider data (user information inside your service that provides user tokens).

But with that solution you will find a small problem: if a support user must get all the orders and in another moment only its orders you won't find an easy way to implement this. If your requirements demand that you provide both use cases for support users you will need another solution.

In that case another solution would be to provide two different endpoints (API Gateway API's) touching the same backend lambda. In the *normal* endpoint you forward the request to the backend and the lambda gets all the orders for the user. In the *support* endpoint you add something else to the request (can be a query parameter or a http header).

For a more secure solution, your *support* endpoint must not allow requests from people outside the support group. And if you go for a query parameter alternative, you must block this exact query param in the *normal* endpoint. Someone can abuse the *normal* api sending the query param for it and get all the orders if you just forward the query params downstream.

You will do all this different configuration in the integration request of AWS API Gateway. You can find how it works [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-request.html).

Comment: Thanks for the details. At the end is RBAC vs API gateway pattern. I think the API Gateways API's + Cognito is the best solution. But, it will add an extra layer: "API GW user" will execute lambda function 1, which will call Orders API filtering by the authentication user. Then, "API GW support" will execute directly Orders API. The lambda function 1 (forwarder + filter) will add latency, right?

Comment: Based on your commend I don't know if I understood correctly your architecture. Maybe you can clarify what do you mean by Orders API being called by lambda 1. I was imagining that lambda 1 would implement Orders API logic.

Comment: Order API is a service to be consumed by 2 API Gateways (user and support). I have to do the extra logic (filter the orders of the user or get all the orders) in the Gateway. So, the communication will be:
User -> API Gateway Users -> Lambda1 (call /orders?user=1) -> Order API -> Lambda. Is this a good design?

Comment: In my point of view yes!! more details would be needed for a more informed opinion... but even with more details probably yes...